# Can I apply a goal to a parent item and then have it apply to all of its children?

Tags: goals, marketing-control-panel, weblog

I am setting up a scoring model on our new site in Marketing Control Panel.  One of our simple goals is 'Read a Blog Post'.  I would like to add that goal to the parent node and then instead of adding it to each of the children it would just inherit from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes. But you may not have access to it.

To achieve what you ask; the goal would need to be configured on Standard Values for the page type template of "Blog Post". It is relatively simple to set up, but would need to be done by someone with `Sitecore Developer` or `Is Administrator` privileges on your solution.

Edit:

Technically this wouldn't do it in the exact way you ask; allow you to set a goal on a parent that then propagates to child items. But it should achieve your desired result.